# Can I do a negation of a POSIX bracket expression?

Tags: regex, posix

I know I can search for something matching a space with the POSIX bracket expression `[[:space:]]`. Can I do a search for something not matching a space using a POSIX bracket expression? In particular, the characters it should match include letters, and parentheses (`(`).

`[[:graph:]]` looks somewhat vague:

> `[[:graph:]]` - Non-blank character (excludes spaces, control characters, and similar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You confuse two things here: a [bracket expression and a POSIX character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). The outer `[...]` is a bracket expression, and it can be negated with a `^` that immediately follows `[`. A POSIX character class is a `[:`+`name`+`:]` construct that only works inside bracket expressions.

So, in your case, `[[:space:]]` pattern is a bracket expression containing just 1 POSIX character class that matches a whitespace:

- `[` - opening a bracket expression

  - `[:space:]` - a POSIX character class for whitespace
- `]` -  closing bracket of the bracket expression.

To negate it, just add the `^` as in usual NFA [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): `[^[:space:]]`.

Note I deliberately differentiate the terms "bracket expression", "POSIX character class" and "character class" since POSIX and common NFA regex worlds adhere to different terminology.

Comment: For anyone unfamiliar with NFA: [tag:nfa]. Nondeterministic finite automaton.

Comment: Yes, here, by common NFA engines I mean most of the non-POSIX engines (such as Ruby's Onigmo, for example).

Answer (score 3):

Well, if

```
'foo bar'[ /[[:space:]]/ ] # => " "
```

matches a space, why doesn't this work?

```
'foo bar'[ /[^[[:space:]]]/ ] # => "f"
```

For instance, something like this:

```
'foo bar'.scan(/[^[[:space:]]]+/) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

It's important to remember that `[[:space:]]` is a character class, just as `\s` or `\d` or their negated versions are. Since `\S` is akin to `[^\s]` we can use `[^[[:space:]]]`.

---

> I think that should be [^[:space:]] since [:space:] is what expands inside the set notation [...].

I use the `[[...]]` form because that's what is documented in [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes).

For clarity, here are some examples not using the double-brackets as shown in the documentation, but instead following the comments below:

```
'foo bar'[ /[[:space:]]/    ]# => " "
'foo bar'[ /[^[:space:]]/   ]# => "f"
'foo bar'[ /[^[[:space:]]]/ ]# => "f"
```

Note that this doesn't work:

```
'foo bar'[ /[:space:]/      ]# => "a"
```

`/[:space:]/` is being interpreted by the regex engine as:

```
/[:space]/
```

which is a regular character-set, not a meta form. That's why it matches `'a'` in "foo bar".

Comment: I think that should be `[^[:space:]]` since `[:space:]` is what expands inside the set notation `[...]`.

Comment: It seems that both work in Ruby, but `[^[:space:]]` is what most other regex engines use.

Comment: Using `String#[]` is very cool, but a little confusing for this particular answer.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm not sure why but `[^[[:space]]]` and `[^[:space:]]` seem to produce identical results. Maybe the extra square brackets are ignored?

Comment: Note that in `/[...]/` there's an outer set of brackets, and `[:space:]` is nested within that, hence `/[[:space:]]/` is valid. To invert it you spike in a `^` as the first character: `/[^...]/` which is `/[^[:space:]]/` in this case.

Comment: *«Since \S is akin to [^\s]…»* — there is perhaps a misconception with `[\s]` or `[^\s]` (I stumbled upon recently myself using `sed` and `grep` as well): there is no character *class* `[\s]` or `[^\s]`, I think, it just finds “s” or *not*-“s”. So `[[:space:]]` is `\s` but not `[\s]`. Try `echo 'abcdef … stuvw' | grep -o '[^s]*'` and you’ll see that it misses the ‘s’ only. Perhaps to note this in your answer above to be aware of `[^\s]` not being `[^[:space:]]`, or not to get confused aso..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this variation also does the trick:

```
/[[:^alpha:]]+/.match("ab12")
```

Results in:

```
#<MatchData "12">
```